# when download application from url (.plist) multi time

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, xcode9

I download an application from url, but this multi time between Calls to Url and see the app begin to download, 
How can I to abbreviate the time, and see immediately that the application began to download,
example code:

```
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://.....plist"] ;
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

The problem began ios 10

Comment: Please explain ` but this multi time between Calls to Url and see the app begin to download, How can I to abbreviate the time`

Comment: It takes a long time since I turn to url and until I see on the screen that the app has started to drop